# VBA Excel code to check if certain text is found in selection, then change cell text

Tags: excel, vba

I am working in the pricing department, I made a macro to change the part number into a hyperlink using this code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim userResponce As Range

On Error Resume Next
Set userResponce = Application.InputBox("select a range with the mouse", Default: = Selection.Address, Type: = 8)
On Error GoTo 0
If userResponce Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Cancel clicked"
Else
MsgBox "You selected " & userResponce.Address
End If

For Each xCell In userResponce
If xCell.Value < > ""
Then
xCell.NumberFormat = "@"
xCell.Value = Trim(xCell.Value)
URL = "~pricer.cfm?part_number=" & xCell.Value & "&buyQty=0&buyUofm=1"
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor: = xCell, Address: = URL, TextToDisplay: = xCell.Value
End If

Next xCell
```

Now, I am trying to test if the cell content starts with a certain prefix, if it does I wanna add - after it, I know it is done using this

```
If InStr(1, celltxt, "TK") Then
```

but not sure how to run it, so it would cover my selection and not one cell.

Comment: I find a trouble trying to place a hyphen after the text I am searching for, in this case TK220 I want it to be TK-220

Comment: well the string that must match is your decision, the answer that i gave does the selection of the cells.

Comment: I fixed it with

`code`
If xCell.Value <> "" Then
       If InStr(1, xCell.Value, "TN") > 0 And InStr(1, xCell.Value, "-") < 1 Then
       S = xCell.Value
       S = Right(xCell.Value, Len(xCell.Value) - 2)
        xCell.Value = "TN-" & S
        End If
`code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should make the last If statement to select the cells that make that Match. So the matching cells will take the hyperlink substitution and the none matching doesn't.

```
If xCell.value <> "" and InStr(1, cellTxt, "TK") > 0 Then
{...}
End If
```